# make cannot work in Cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I met a problem with c code compilation in Cygwin.
my environment is Cygwin in Window Xp,

```
$ which make
/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/make

$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc.exe
```

My makefile looks like:

```
CC=cc
CFLAGS= -g  -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic
EXE=graph
SRCS=graph.c
$(EXE):$(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) -o $(EXE)
CLEAN:
        rm -fr $(OBJS) $(EXE)*
```

The file `graph.c` is in the same folder with `cc`.

I run `make`, but it shows

```
cc -g  -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic graph.c -o graph
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\cygwin\bin\cc.exe, cc -g -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic graph.c -o graph, ...) failed.
make (e=5): Access is denied.
make: *** [graph] Error 5
```

But when I run `cc -g  -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic graph.c -o graph`
it works fine.

I am new to Cygwin, what is the problem with my settings or the makefile?

Comment: This question is not "too localized". It helped me fix my problem - the answer is spot on.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is your `$PATH`.

It looks like you've installed both MinGW and Cygwin. They're similar but different environments.

The Cygwin `make` command is `/usr/bin/make` (typically `C:\cygwin\bin\make`). You're invoking the MinGW `make` command, `/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/make` (`C:\MinGW\bin/make`).  But it's trying to invoke the Cygwin `cc` command, `/usr/bin/cc` (`C:\cygwin\bin\cc`).

Adjust your `$PATH` so that `/usr/bin` appears *before* `/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin`, and you should be ok. You probably want to do this by modifying your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: Thanks， I downloading the latest Cygwin, the make is in the /usr/bin, all are fine.

Comment: @Weida: Glad I could help. Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)?